# Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-function

I received this error message while trying to execute below SQL.

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FUNCTION'.
>   Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

SQL:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DBO.TRACKING WHERE CR = 123)) 

BEGIN

  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDFDate]()
  RETURNS DATETIME
  AS BEGIN
     RETURN CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATETIME)
  END
END
```

Am I not allowed to create a Function inside if statement ?

Comment: this is not how you would call a function. You will need to create the function then call it. Also looking at your function it is not really doing anything except casting '9999-12-31' as date. Why would you need a function when your date is static

Comment: I suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create  a function inside an if statment this way you will get the following warning

> Incorrect syntax: `CREATE FUNCTION` must be the only statment in the batch

[image]

you can do it by creating a variable stor the create query in this variable and execute it:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DBO.TRACKING WHERE CR = 123)) 

BEGIN

 DECLARE @strQuery AS VARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @strQuery = '

  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDFDate]()
  RETURNS DATETIME
  AS BEGIN
     RETURN CAST(''9999-12-31'' AS DATETIME)
  END
'

EXEC(@strQuery)

END
```

[image]

**but i didn't understand why creating a function to return a static value??!!**

Answer (score 2):

There are no reasons why you would want to create functions inside a stored procedure during runtime. Functions in SQL SERVER work similarly to stored procedures, so if you want to create a function you need to do it outside of the context and scope of a stored procedure and it will be saved on your database to be accessed at any time.

Ontopic, if you only want to exhibit that date value you could just remove the function creation and select the datetime result as this:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM DBO.TRACKING WHERE CR = 123)) 
BEGIN    
  SELECT CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATETIME)
END
```

PS: Don't use "SELECT *" when you just want to know if some value exists. It creates unnecessary overhead to bring all columns when you just want to know if anything exists.